# How to make an Angular PWA installable?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to make an installable PWA with Angular.

Following the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro), I ran `ng add @angular/pwa` to make my app a PWA. It worked fine. Then I built it with `ng build` and served the build using `http-server`.

The service worker seems to be working fine, it caches assets, keeps working when I disable the internet, etc.

However, at this point I expected it to ask if the user wants to install the app, but it doesn't. I checked the [MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Installable_PWAs) and the app seems to meet all the requirements. On the other hand, this [web.dev page](https://web.dev/install-criteria/) says one of the install criteria to be met is to meet a given user engagement heuristic.

So I have no idea for which reason the install hint is not showing, it can be anything between:

- Messed up installation
- I'm testing it from a desktop browser, on http://localhost
- I have to meet the engagement criteria

In case it helps, here are some of the related files:

**manifest.webmanifest**

```json
{
  "name": "SiAQ",
  "short_name": "siaq",
  "description": "Aplicativo móvel do Sistema de Atendimento aos Queimados (SiAQ)",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "./",
  "start_url": "./",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    }
  ]
}
```

**ngsw-config.json**

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(svg|cur|jpg|jpeg|png|apng|webp|avif|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, my PWA was getting a warning becuase in the `manifest.webmanifest` I was setting the purpose of my icons to `"maskable any"`. Just had to remove this property from all the icons (returning to the default value) for it to work fine.

You can check if everything is fine with your PWA by opening dev tools and going to Application -> Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did everything just fine. And the `@angular/pwa` should do all the work from the box. The only guess I have it's that you're building your app, not in the `prod` mode.

Try to follow the next steps:

1. `ng build --prod`
2. `cd dist/<proj_name>`
3. `http-server`

Comment: Hmm, good idea! But I think that's not the case. When I build with `--prod`, the CLI says this flag is deprecated since it builds for prod by default now.

Comment: Just check it. It helped in my case, despite I have the same configuration.

Comment: Try
ng build --configuration=production

Comment: @TatyanaMolchanova `ng build --prod` command does it